# Restore Aurora DB from point in time before retention earliest restorable time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

Here's the situation. I have an Aurora Serverless MySQL compatible database that had the default backup retention period set at 1 day. I made some modifications Saturday morning and just now realized that it resulted in a large amount of data loss. The earliest restorable point is *after* the destructive changes (I already tried restoring with no luck).

Is there any way possible to retrieve the lost data?

Comment: Do you have any snapshots of your database? Snapshot do not expire.

Comment: @Marcin I do, but the most recent one is from October

Comment: Maybe there were some data dumps as well, to s3 or other services?

Comment: @Marcin no, unfortunately. Is there any way the logs can be of use?

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say that this is probably an opportunity for you to rethink your deployment and backup strategy :(

Comment: @Maurice Yeah, I reached out to AWS and they gave me the same answer. Going forward I'm setting 7 hours as the minimum retention period with periodic snapshots

Comment: Under the assumption that you mean days instead of hours I think that's reasonable :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to summarize the points from the comments:

There are multiple types of backups available and two native ones that are builtin with RDS/Aurora. The built-in ones are:

- Automatic Snapshots, which allow for point in time recovery in a retention period that you can configure between 1 and 35 days if I recall correctly. These snapshots are tied to the lifecycle of your database. If the database is terminated, the snapshots are also removed.
- Manual Snapshots can be created at any time through an API-Call. These have a lifecycle that's separate from the database, so if you delete the database, the snapshots are retained.

Aside from the built-in mechanisms, you can always export your data to services like S3 using tools such as mysqldump or a `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` query.

If your issue happened before the retention period of the automatic snapshots, your manual snapshots are too old and you don't have external snapshots, you're unfortunately out of luck, that data is gone - which the AWS support has already confirmed.